# Read file Contents in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to read file contents from .txt file and need to store those contents in database. This need for cms pages. I want to load cms pages while run my seeds file. 
Any one Please..

Comment: Err. This doesn't look like a clearly composed question. Are you looking for file uploading, sir?

Comment: this not for uploading. i want to load cms pages while run seeds file. can you please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.read("PATH_TO_FILE")
```

Then write to db as usually.